# 16.04 (from 14.04) upgrade failure will not boot in recovery mode (at password prompt enters suspend)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, 16.04, suspend

Last night I was prompted to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 and selected OK.  This morning, normal boot results in:

```
Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen
```

Cannot enter terminal or get any other response, other than power button to shut down.  Booting in Recovery Mode results in two possibilities:
1. Command line login.  Typing user results in password prompt and immediate suspend.  Password cannot be entered.
2. Boots to point of "Starting Suspend" message and then is suspended.

During boot, the error "Failed to start Kernel Modules" appears.

This is a dual boot system with Windows 10 and GRUB.  It appears to need a fresh Ubuntu install.  Is there anything less drastic possible?